# Remove one nesting level from a list of lists

Tags: gap

I have a list with entries like

```
e:=[[[1,2]],[[3,4]],[[5,6]]];
```

I want to remove double list brackets to get a list looking like

```
result:=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
```

How can I do this in GAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-liner would be

```
gap> List(e,x->x[1]);
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

If you want to modify the list **in place**, do

```
gap> for i in [1..Length(e)] do
> e[i]:=e[i][1];
> od;
gap> e;
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> k:=[];
>
> for i in [1..length(e)] do
>
> Add(k,e[i][1]);
>
> od;
>
> k;

this code worked. Thanks.

Comment: If you intensively work with lists, I would like to recommend to read in details these two chapters from [Tutorial](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap3.html) and [Reference Manual](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap21.html).